# Duplicate a DevOps collection

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

I wanted to do some experiments on our on-prem DevOps collection database. Alas, I'm having a bit trouble actually duplicating said collection. I mean, it's easy enough to take a backup of the database, but now I'd like to restore the collection database under a new name in DevOps.

Except DevOps doesn't even see the restored collection database. Now, granted, chances are it's because the backup was performed while the collection was attached (since this is for testing I'm not particularly worried about breaking anything on said duplicated collection; the same cannot be said about the rest of the system, obviously). There's there's a very good chance that some collection IDs might be duplicated, given this is a copy.

Is it possible to duplicate a collection in DevOps on-prem? Or would any kind of duplication / testing require a whole new DevOps server instance?

PS. While not important to this question, it might shed some light on what I am trying to do. I wanted to see if the SQL changes suggested by someone here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a/614232 are actually worth it. I don't want to stop our main / production DevOps collection for obvious reasons and instead wanted to duplicate it and run the SQL scripts on such a cloned collection...